# Onchange Phone language in Android my App layout change

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-ios

when i change my phone language it effect my App also,,i want that whatever the phone language as,,not effected my App layouts,for example my App is an English language i want the app language and layouts remain same,,while phone language keep changing

Answer (score 1):

Changing the language is considered a configuration change, just like rotating the device or switching the UI from light- to dark mode. Your activity is then recreated and loaded with the appropriate resources.

If you wan't to handle a configuration change yourself, you need to specify this in your manifest for your activities as stated [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes#HandlingTheChange).

```
<activity android:name=".MyActivity"
          android:configChanges="locale"
          android:label="@string/app_name">
```

You can find other valid values for `configChanges` [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#config).